# error from snowsql CLI - new db cannot be found

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using AccountAdmin role I created new DB 'SF_TUTS', new table 'emp_basic ' and warehouse 'sf_tuts_wh' from web interface worksheet. Later I opened SnowSQL CLI to execute PUT command to load data into stage. It errors out with message the db cannot be found.

abcd#COMPUTE_WH@(no database).(no schema)>put file://c:\temp\employees0*.csv @sf_tuts.public.%emp_basic;
002003 (02000): SQL compilation error:
Database 'SF_TUTS' does not exist or not authorized.

alos receiving error saying db cannot be found

abcd#COMPUTE_WH@(no database).(no schema)>select current_database(), current_schema();

| CURRENT_DATABASE() | CURRENT_SCHEMA() |
|--------------------+------------------|
| NULL               | NULL             |

I can see both database and table in the web interface.
please advice..

Comment: Are you using the same user and role in both places? Permissions need to be set appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the default role of the main user is SYSADMIN (*Not sure if it's documented*). When using UI, you switch to the role accountadmin, create databases and other stuff, and your worksheets remember your role, so when you re-open the worksheet, you still use the role accountadmin, but when you connect using SnowSQL, your user logs in with the default role (SYSADMIN). This is probably why you get errors. As a workaround:

You may switch to the role accountadmin before running other commands:

```
user accountadmin
```

You may change the default role of your user:

```
alter user xyz set DEFAULT_ROLE = accountadmin;
```

Or change the parameters of your SnowSQL configuration/set parameters to use the role accountadmin.